# How do you add Graphics to a Container in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, containers

I am trying to add Graphics to my Container, however, it is giving me an error because a Container can only accept Components. Is there any way to bypass this issue?

I did try casting it but that didn't work.

```
private final int WIDTH = 1200; // Width for Window private final int HEIGHT = 800; // Height for Window private static Graphics2D canvasOriginal; // Canvas

static Graphics canvas = (Graphics) canvasOriginal;

public Graph_GUI (Container drawable, JFrame window) { // GUI

  super("CSV Graph");

  drawable = getContentPane();

  drawable.add(canvas);

  setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

}
```

Comment: That looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you trying to achieve by using `drawable.add(canvas)`?

Comment: You do custom painting on a JPanel with the Graphics object passed to the panel in the paintComponent() method. Then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry if I didn't explain clearly. I didn't show my full code, but I am graphing a 2d Array by using an arrayList of my point class, and graphing them on graphics. It's fixed now. Thanks for replying though!